# OutOfMemory error android

Tags: android, android-animation, out-of-memory

I am developing an android game. it is almost finished and tried it in 10.1 tablets, nexus 7, nexus 4, HTC senstation it worked on all of them. However, when I tried it on Galaxy s3 I got OutofMemory error when Im calling pics in frame animation xml. now I solved this problem by resizing the pics in xhdpi folder but the results wasn't satisfying. Is there any sufficient method I can use to rescale pics that are displayed in anim to do a frame animation.

Here is the code:

```
public class Logo extends Activity {

    private ImageView iv;
    Thread timer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_logo);

        iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        iv.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.anime);

        // thread for animating the logo and moving to next activity after
        // display.
        timer = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(7000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    //Intent i = new Intent();
                    //i.setClass(Logo.this, StartPoint.class);
                    //startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        AnimationDrawable anime = (AnimationDrawable) iv.getBackground();
        if (hasFocus) {
            anime.start();
            timer.start();
        } else {
            anime.stop();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.logo, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();
        finish(); // to remove this activity.
    }
}
```

here is the anime.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
android:oneshot="true">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a1" android:duration="60" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a2" android:duration="60" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a3" android:duration="60" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a4" android:duration="60" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a5" android:duration="60" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a6" android:duration="60" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a7" android:duration="60" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a8" android:duration="60" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a9" android:duration="60" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a10" android:duration="60" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a11" android:duration="60" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a12" android:duration="60" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a13" android:duration="60" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a14" android:duration="60" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a15" android:duration="60" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a16" android:duration="60" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a17" android:duration="60" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a18" android:duration="60" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a19" android:duration="60" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a20" android:duration="60" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a21" android:duration="60" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a22" android:duration="60" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a23" android:duration="60" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a24" android:duration="60" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a25" android:duration="60" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a26" android:duration="60" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a27" android:duration="60" />

</animation-list>
```

Now I saw many answers that illustrates bitmapFactory.options
but how can I apply these options on xml file and if it isnt possible. is there any other methods I can use instead of resizing the pics.
Thank you in advance.

here I tried to apply the code programmaticaly and still got the same error:

```
//onCreate and thread then 
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    BitmapDrawable frame1 = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a1);
    BitmapDrawable frame2 = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a2);
    BitmapDrawable frame3 = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a3);
    BitmapDrawable frame4 = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a4);
    BitmapDrawable frame5 = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a5);
    BitmapDrawable frame6 = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a6);
    BitmapDrawable frame7 = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a7);
    BitmapDrawable frame8 = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a8);
    BitmapDrawable frame9 = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a9);
    BitmapDrawable frame10 = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a10);
    BitmapDrawable frame11 = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a11);
    BitmapDrawable frame12 = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a12);
    BitmapDrawable frame13 = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a13);
    BitmapDrawable frame14 = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a14);
    BitmapDrawable frame15 = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a15);
    BitmapDrawable frame16 = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a16);
    BitmapDrawable frame17 = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a17);
    BitmapDrawable frame18 = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a18);
    BitmapDrawable frame19 = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a19);
    BitmapDrawable frame20 = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a20);
    BitmapDrawable frame21 = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a21);
    BitmapDrawable frame22 = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a22);
    BitmapDrawable frame23 = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a23);
    BitmapDrawable frame24 = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a24);
    BitmapDrawable frame25 = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a25);
    BitmapDrawable frame26 = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a26);
    BitmapDrawable frame27 = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a27);

    final AnimationDrawable anime = new AnimationDrawable();
    anime.setOneShot(true);
    anime.addFrame(frame1, 60);
    anime.addFrame(frame2, 60);
    anime.addFrame(frame3, 60);
    anime.addFrame(frame4, 60);
    anime.addFrame(frame5, 60);
    anime.addFrame(frame6, 60);
    anime.addFrame(frame7, 60);
    anime.addFrame(frame8, 60);
    anime.addFrame(frame9, 60);
    anime.addFrame(frame10, 60);
    anime.addFrame(frame11, 60);
    anime.addFrame(frame12, 60);
    anime.addFrame(frame13, 60);
    anime.addFrame(frame14, 60);
    anime.addFrame(frame15, 60);
    anime.addFrame(frame16, 60);
    anime.addFrame(frame17, 60);
    anime.addFrame(frame18, 60);
    anime.addFrame(frame19, 60);
    anime.addFrame(frame20, 60);
    anime.addFrame(frame21, 60);
    anime.addFrame(frame22, 60);
    anime.addFrame(frame23, 60);
    anime.addFrame(frame24, 60);
    anime.addFrame(frame25, 60);
    anime.addFrame(frame26, 60);
    anime.addFrame(frame27, 60);


    iv.setBackgroundDrawable(anime);
    if (hasFocus) {
        anime.start();
        timer.start();
    }

    else
        anime.stop();
}
```

Comment: Have You tried to create animation programmatically?

Comment: Nope, I didnt think that it was possible, im going to read about it, So you are saying that if i implemented it in programmatically i can add the bitmapfactory's options on the pics?

Comment: well the thing is you never know which device can support this and which device cannot..try checking the heap memory in DDMS views for the devices you have..also as sandrstar suggested u can make animation programmatically..it does resolves the problem often

Comment: Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563726/set-android-animation-list-programmatically it provides necessary links for simplest variant.

Comment: Applied them programmatically and still got outofmemory error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Galaxy S3 in fact has relatively a small default heap size(32MB) for its specs.

You can temporary workaround this issue requesting a larger heap and checking if this fixes your problem.

```
<application android:largeHeap="true">
        . . .
</application>
```

Then I would work on the size and type of the frame resources.

Cheers.

Comment: Even after adding it, I still got the error, does it mean I am using way too much memory?! I guess Ill just resize the pics.

Comment: Can you give me more details on the resolution size and format of the resources?
And maybe what type of animation(whole screen,just a part of it) are you trying to accomplish.

Comment: I have 27 pics, each pic has 1000*600 dimension with 300dpi on both horizontally and vertically. the size of each pic is 55.7 KB.
Im using the picture to display a splash screen for the game, though the same format worked on Nexus 4 and other devices I mentioned earlier

Comment: Well you cannot use this amount of memory in fact, not even with largeHeap enabled. 

A sigle image of this type requires approximately 4,8 MB for Android to allocate without compression at render time.

27 of these make 127 MB.

You can decode them at 4bits per component bit this would still be way too much for an animation.

Hope I've helped.

Cheers!

Comment: thanks :) I have changed the pic dimension to 800*480 and it works perfectly